# prove equality $\lim_{n\to\infty}n(\sqrt[n]{a} - 1) = \ln a $

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n(\sqrt[n]{a} - 1) = \ln a $$
since $a > 0$

My attempt is

$\lim_{n\to\infty}n(\sqrt[n]{a} - 1) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \ln e^{n(\sqrt[n]{a} - 1)} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \ln e^{(n\sqrt[n]{a} - n)} $

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \ln e^{(n\sqrt[n]{a} - n)} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \ln \frac{e^{n\sqrt[n]{a}}}{e^n} $

And I do not know what to do then.

Comment: set $\sqrt[n]{a}-1=\frac{1}{m}$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner so I got $\lim \ln e^{\frac{n}{m}}$ how it can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have $\sqrt[n]{a}-1=\frac{1}{m}$ and from here we get $$n=\frac{\log(a)}{\log\left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)}$$

Comment: Please may you give more explanations? I really interested in you solution but I can't get it.

Comment: calculate $n\cdot \frac{1}{m}$

Comment: how can I calculate it? It's just n if m is constant but when m is depending on n so what can you do with that?

Comment: I got your main idea and stuck again. $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln a}{\ln (\frac{1}{m} + 1)m}$ and so haven't make denominator equal to 1. I need a hint.

Comment: thus you will get $$n\cdot \frac{1}{m}=\frac{\log(a)}{m\log\left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)}$$

Comment: yeah, I wrote the same. Why denominator is 1?

Answer (score 1):

Write the original expression as
$$\frac{a^{1/n} - a^0}{\frac{1}{n} - 0}.$$
So that the limit of it can be viewed as the derivative of $a^x$ at $x = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a= e^b$. Then you have to prove:
$$ \lim_{n \to +\infty}n \left(e^{b/n}-1\right) = b. \tag{1}$$
The exponential function is a convex function, hence $e^{x}\geq x+1$ implies $n\left(e^{b/n}-1\right)\geq b$.

On the other hand, $\frac{e^x-1}{x}$ is a convex function on $(0,1]$, hence $e^{x}-1\leq x\left(1+(e-2)x\right)$ for every $x\in(0,1]$ implies that the original limit is $\color{red}{b=\log a}$ by squeezing.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n(\sqrt[n]{a} - 1) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^{\frac{1}{n}} - 1}{\frac{1}{n}} $$
by using L'Hopital Rule
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-\frac{(\ln a)a^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n^2} }{-\frac{1}{n^2}}=\ln a$$