# Elementary proof of $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(a^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)=\ln a$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm trying to proof that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(a^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)=\ln a$$
without using limit of function. I can use only sequence limits. The most elementary proof.

Below you can find my solution, but I'm not sure if it's OK.

Started with limit of
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\log_a\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n\log_a\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\log_a\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}=\frac{1}{\log_a e}=\ln a$$

Then let's create new sequence $b_n$ such that $b_n=a^{\frac{1}{n}}-1$. From definition of $b_n$ I can find expresion for $\frac{1}{n}$

$$
b_n=a^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\Rightarrow b_n+1=a^{\frac{1}{n}}\Rightarrow \log_a\left(b_n+1\right)=\frac{1}{n}
$$

We can see that

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=0=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}
$$

Next step is problematic for me. $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=0$. So I can replace those expressions (can I?)

Then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(a^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{\frac{1}{n}}\overbrace{=}^{??}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b_n}{\log_a\left(b_n+1\right)}=\ln a
$$

Is there any theorem about replacing similar sequences to calculate limits? Without involving definition of limit of function. Is there any simpler proof (from some inequalities for instance) of this limit?

Comment: More generally, if $a_n$ is a positive sequence, then $a_n^n$ converges to $a$ if and only if  $n(a_n-1)\to\log a.$

Comment: Your question appears to be an abstract duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362452/the-limit-as-n-approaches-infinity-of-na1-n-1) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1529075/prove-equality-lim-n-to-inftyn-sqrtna-1-ln-a?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: "without using limit of function." Are we allowed to use Maclurin expansion of $\ln$ or generalised Binomial expansion?

Answer (score 1):

Consider letting $a = e^b$ such that the expression becomes

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(e^{\frac{b}{n}}-1\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty}n\left((e^b)^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)$$

Since

$$e^b = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \Big(1 + \frac{b}{n}\Big)^n (*)$$

The expression becomes

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(1+ \frac{b}{n}-1\right) = b = \log(a)$$

(Note: $(*)$ can be proven easily if you let $e^b = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{n})^{bn}$, and let $z = bn$ such that $z$ also goes to infinity, so $n = \frac{z}{b}$ and the expression can be re-written as $e^b = \lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} (1 + \frac{b}{z})^{z}.$ This works assuming $b$ is non-negative, and expanding it to include negatives is not hard.

Answer (score 0):

Remark that $\lim\limits_{X\to 0}\frac{e^X-1}{X} = 1$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(a^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln a}-1}{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln a}-1}{\frac{1}{n}\ln a}\ln a = \lim_{X\to0}\frac{e^{X}-1}{X}\ln a = \ln a$$

Comment: I think you want $X\to0,$ not $X\to\infty.$

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to predict whether it will seem simple or not, but I'll be based on simple inequalities and fact $e^{\frac{1}{n}}\to 1$:

knowing $\left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^n <e < \left(1+\frac{1}{n-1} \right)^n$, we can found $1 < n\left(e^{\frac{1}{n}} -1\right) < 1+ \frac{1}{n-1}$ i.e. $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}n\left(e^{\frac{1}{n}} -1\right) = 1$.

Now let's consider $a>1$. Then  $y_n=n\left(a^{\frac{1}{n}} -1\right) = n \left(e^{\frac{\ln a}{n}} -1\right) = z_n\left(e^{\frac{1}{z_n}} -1\right)\ln a$. Where $z_n=\frac{n}{\ln a}\to +\infty$. Let's denote $\alpha_n=\left\lfloor z_n \right\rfloor$, then we have estimations:

$$\ln a \cdot \alpha_n \left(e^{\frac{1}{\alpha_n+1}} -1\right) < y_n < \ln a \cdot (\alpha_n +1) \left(e^{\frac{1}{\alpha_n}} -1\right)\quad(1)$$
Now, because subsequence have same limit as sequence, holds $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\alpha_n \left(e^{\frac{1}{\alpha_n}} -1\right)=1$ and left and right sides in $(1)$ will have limit $\ln a$ i.e. it will have $y_n$.

Case $0<a<1$ comes from considered.